# Why I can't write "implements AClass" in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm

In Java people often define an interface together with a class and use interface name instead of class name where possible, in order to allow new implementations later. Here the logical interface is duplicated.

This kind of "just in case" duplication would not be necessary if Java allowed using a class as an interface eg: `class MyScanner extends MyStuff implements java.util.Scanner`. Also this would ease the situation where I need to provide a class-type but I don't want to extend that class.

As I understand, "implementing a class" would be rejected not only by the compiler but also by the JVM (if I hacked this declaration into classfile). Are there some technical difficulties for this or it's not regarded as important thing? It doesn't look like a backward-compatiblity problem (I mean, old code would run fine if JVM supported this).

EDIT: for clarification, I will copy here StriplingWarrior's much better wording of the same questions:

> Why can't a class "implement" another class's method contract without actually extending that class? Is it a technical issue? Would it somehow open us up to some issues that the OP can't foresee?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have a question. If you have a proposal for a language extension, this really isn't the place.

Comment: well, look carefully Konstantin, or search for a question-mark :)

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik: I disagree. I think this is a well-thought-out question: Why can't a class "implement" another class's method contract without actually extending that class? Is it a technical issue? Would it somehow open us up to some issues that the OP can't foresee? I think it counts as a programming question.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior  thanks, you expressed that question in a much better way!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do I understant correctly that `MyClass implements AClass` would mean that `MyClass` must provide (or inherit) implementations for all public methods that `AClass` has? I.e. each class implicitly defines an interface consisting of its public methods?

If so, then the problem I see with that is that interfaces are really something very different from classes, and the two should not be mixed like that. Interfaces define a contract, classes an implementation. A consequence of that: The functionality of classes can be extended relatively freely, but not so interfaces with existing implementations.

So there you have a very concrete reason why your suggestion would be bad: **you could never add any public method to any class without risking to break some code that `implements` that class.**

And on the other hand, what problems would it solve? The code duplication when you have an interface with a single implementation? How about solving that by not doing it? IMO it's usually something done by people doing TDD dogmatically while using outdated mocking frameworks not capable of mocking concrete classes.

Comment: Point in bold is very solid. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

The issue is [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#Criticisms). If you try to extend or implement two classes, there are potential semantic issues.

You CAN implement multiple interfaces, as well as extend from one class. But you can only implement interfaces, which get around most of the problems with multiple inheritance simply by forcing the specification to be declarative in nature, requiring the implementer to implement the methods directly. In that case, method conflicts are resolved by the simple expedient of implementing one method and having it count for both interfaces.

Comment: it was my impression that the OP was asking why you can't implement, say, 'String's interface, even though it doesn't have an explicit interface defined. Is that correct, OP?

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't want the implementation from that class, only it's type (it's "logical" interface). I will clarify my question.

Comment: Well, in that case it just boils down to "that's how Java works". And a lot of popular object-oriented languages do that. If you want something different, may I recommend Go? Go is a language that has interfaces (rather than real classes necessarily); you automatically implement an interface simply by defining the right methods. There are plenty of one- or zero-method interfaces. You also might want to try a functional programming language.

Comment: @jk, yes, that's what I meant. btw, what means OP ?

Comment: @Aivar: Original poster. Here it means the person who asked this question.

Comment: @Aivar: See @Michael Borgwardt's answer explaining the "logic" behind the Java design decision to separate classes from interfaces. It all depends on how you see classes and interfaces should be. Many Java people are stuck in that mindset (not that I'm saying Michael Borgwardt is necessarily one). I personally see classes and interfaces as being potentially more fluid.

Comment: @Platinum: you need to distinguish between concepts and language mechanisms. The concept of a contract that needs to be strictly defined and cannot be easily changed because "foreign" code depends on it is something I don't think you can avoid if you develop complex systems. Java happens to support this concept directly with a language mechanism. That mechanism then often gets used for other things where you may want more flexible behaviour. Especially if you come from a language using duck typing, which is more or less the directly opposite direction to approach the concept from.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: Believe it or not, we're basically in agreement. I completely agree that you have to separate concepts and language mechanisms... but I see a lot of OOP fashionistas who don't, and it's a little sad when a language is bashed just because it allows for a different kind of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated before, this is how the standard is defined and not being a part of the decision making process I can only chip in with my $0.02.

This is not as much about duplicate logical interfaces, but a standard for creating an API that you would like to be flexible. It is considered a good design practice, even in languages that support multiple inheritance, to expose interfaces from an API.

Given the current state of IDE's it is quite easy to not do this up front and then refactor later when you decide you need multiple implementations of a given type.

There may also be use cases against this where inside your code you have a strong dependency on the functionality of a class and by having a different implementation your code could break. This is the point of being able to do:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
```

rather than

```
InterfaceA a = new ClassA();
```

This may lead to unexpected behavior.